# Sistema de votos positivos y negativos en chat

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy realizando una web mediante `php` e implementando algo de `ajax`. Estoy realizando un chat el cual refresca mensajes en tiempo real, lo cual funciona correctamente.

chat.php

```
             <div class="chathistory">
                <section id="miTabla">

                </section>
              </div>
             <script>

                function enviar(){
                  var id=document.getElementById('id').value;
                  var mensaje=document.getElementById('mensaje').value;
                  var seccion=document.getElementById('seccion').value;

                  $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'chat/ingresochat.php',
                    data:'id='+id +'&mensaje='+mensaje +'&seccion='+seccion,
                    success:function(resp){
                      $("#respa").html(resp);
                    }
                  });
                  return false;
                }

                function limpiar()
                {
                  document.class.mensaje.value = "";
                }

                function tiempoReal()
                    {
                  var seccionar1=document.getElementById('seccionar1').value;
                        var tabla = $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    data:'seccionar1='+seccionar1,
                            url:'chat/mostrarchat.php',
                            dataType:'text',
                            async:false
                        }).responseText;

                        document.getElementById("miTabla").innerHTML = tabla;
                    }
                    setInterval(tiempoReal, 1000);

                </script>
```

Ahora, lo que quiero implementar y no encuentro la forma es la de realizar votos positivos o negativos a los mensajes del chat, también en tiempo real por lo que debería usar `AJAX`. Pero el problema está en que no sé si debo utilizar un `button` o un `submit`, o la manera de poder operar otro `AJAX` en uno ya implementado. Lo que he hecho simplemente es agregar dos botones pero no sé si es la manera correcta en la que deba operar, simplemente quiero que se acumulen esos valores en la base de datos (cantidad de positivos y negativos)

mostrar-chat.php

```
<div class="mensajeus">

        <p><?php echo $mChat['mensaje']; ?></p>

        <div class="estado-mensaje">

            <script>

                function enviarData(){
                    var idrec=document.getElementById('idrec').value;
                    var idenv=document.getElementById('idenv').value;
                    var idchat=document.getElementById('idchat').value;

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                        url:'positivo.php',
                        data:'idrec='+idrec +'&idenv='+idenv +'&idchat='+idchat,
                        success:function(resp){
                            $("#si-respa").html(resp);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }

            </script>

            <div class="positivo-chat">

                <form name="class" method="post" onsubmit="return enviarData();">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idrec" id="idrec" value="<?php echo $mChat['id'];?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idenv" id="idenv" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idchat" id="idchat" value="<?php echo $mChat['id_chat'];?>">
                    <button type="submit" name="button">SI</button>
                    <div id="si-respa"></div>
                </form>

            </div>

            <div class="negativo-chat">
                <form class="" action="" method="post">
                    <button type="submit" name="button">NO</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Agradecería si me pueden ayudar debido a que en cuanto a `AJAX` soy bastante nuevo.

Comment: la forma en que yo lo he implementado es por ejemplo usar dos botones, los cuales se añaden de forma dinámica con los datos, cada botón debe tener un id dinámico con  su respectivas función ajax (positivo) y (negativo) en cada mensaje.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, yo intento realizarlo mediante un button pero no encuentro la forma debido a que la página se me recarga

Answer (score 1):

Se te recarga la pagina porque utilizas formularios , no hace falta en ajax ,simplemente llama a la funcion en el evento Onclick="positivo(this);" de los botones

```
<script>
function positivo(valor){
var idmensaje = $(valor).attr("id");
var valormensaje = $(valor).attr("value");
//ACA LA FUNCION AJAX ACTUALIZAS LA BASE DE DATOS O LO QUE QUIERAS
//Y SIMPLEMENTE SI ES CORRECTO SUMAS EN ESTE CASO
$(valor).attr("value") = valormensaje  +1 ;
}
</script>
```